# Using Hope you a nice day casually

Tags: word-usage

Is saying 'Hope you a nice day' (as in I hope you a nice day) in casual speech considered wrong? What are the possible alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Hope you a nice day” is not grammatical.

The following are:

> I wish you a nice day.

> I hope you **have** a nice day.

The latter is idiomatically shortened to:

> Have a nice day.

Comment: Why though? Isn't saying 'I hope you a nice day' considered grammatically correct? With the discarded pronoun I, shouldn't it still be considered correct?

Comment: No, "I hope you a nice day" is also incorrect.

Comment: @FadyAdal “Have a nice day” is an idiomatic relic of the subjunctive tense, which allows an implied “you” like the imperative tense. “I hope” is present simple and requires an explicit subject.